# NodeJS: Indicate data writing is finished (stdin)

Tags: python, node.js, stdin, child-process, spawn

I'm trying to signal I've finished writing from my main NodeJS process but nothing works

```
pythonProcess.stdin.write(base64Image); // What I'm writing
// None of these worked
pythonProcess.stdin.write("\x04");
pythonProcess.stdin.write("\n");
pythonProcess.stdin.write("\r\n");
pythonProcess.stdin.write(os.EOL);
```

Only sending the `pythonProcess.stdin.end()` works (also tried `cork()` and `uncork()` but didn't work either). Since this is a process I'll be querying often I want to avoid closing and reopening the process every time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to check, are you able to read the base64 data in your python process?

Comment: Only if I send `pythonProcess.stdin.end()`, otherwise it's just stuck on the reading part